# Remove personal template from Visio (plan2)?

Tags: visio

Does anyone know how to remove previously added personal template form Visio (plan2)? It seems this is not as straightforward as I would expect...
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some additional research to find out that while adding .vtpx template, visio converts it to .vstx and stores it (in my case) in Custom Office Templates folder.
All I had to do is remove the corresponding .vstx from that folder and the template disappeared form Personal Templates tab.

Not sure if Custom Office Templates is the default location in all cases, so better search for your [templatename].vstx on your drive.

Credit for idea goes to @Surrogate who hinted that you could define folder for templates. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please check in **File location** window field **Templates**. You can call this window with these steps

1. Select tab **File** at ribbon
2. Select **Options** in bottom of list
3. Select **Advanced**
4. Select **File locations** in bottom of list
   [image]
   Please check: Is your unwanted document located in folder which you can find in **Templates** field in **File locations** window ?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  My "Templates" field is empty and when I click "..." it points to a Documents folder. No visio templates there.

Comment: Ok, please describe how you add this template to landing page which show when MS Visio starts ?

Comment: I've created template myself (Export as Template) and then added it to visio by clinking on .vtpx

Comment: You mean Data Visualizer template ! I haven't Visio Plan 2, and cant help you. Sorry !